# Does completion of $(0,1)$ exists and does there is a metric where $[0,1]$ is not complete

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

This question was asked in a master's exam for which I am preparing and I was unable to find out which result I should use. So, I am posting it here.

> Question: (i) does there exists a metric on which $(0,1)$ is complete? (More generally can you please tell if there always exits a metric such that the space which is fixed while finding the metric is complete?)

> (ii) Does there exists a metric such that $[0,1]$ is not complete?

I studied analysis from Apostol but unable to think on how should I approach this particular question (i.e. which result I should) use. There were 2 more options in question but I worked them out.

Comment: What about the discrete metric on (0,1)?

Comment: For the discrete metric, every Cauchy sequence is stationnary so is convergent.

Comment: For ii) take $d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$ where $f(x) =x$ for $x >0$ and $f(x) =x-1$ for $x \leq 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have a metric space $(X, d)$, a set $Y$ (no topological features necessary), and a bijection $\varphi : Y \to X$. Then
$$d' : Y \times Y \to \Bbb{R} : (y_1, y_2) \mapsto d(\varphi(y_1), \varphi(y_2))$$
defines a metric such that $\varphi$ becomes an isometry between $(X, d)$ and $(Y, d')$. In particular, $(Y, d')$ is complete if and only if $(X, d)$ is complete.

In this case, we can put $(0, 1)$ in bijection with $[0, 1]$, both having cardinality of the continuum. If we inherit the metric from $[0, 1]$, then $(0, 1)$ becomes complete. If we inherit the metric from $(0, 1)$, then $[0, 1]$ becomes incomplete.

EDIT: You can also make $(0, 1)$ complete by putting it into bijection with $\Bbb{R}$ using a homeomorphism like
$$\varphi : (0, 1) \to \Bbb{R} : x \mapsto \tan\left(\pi\left(x - \frac{1}{2}\right)\right).$$
This shows that you can preserve the topology of $(0, 1)$, but yet change whether the space is complete.

On the other hand, we cannot form a homeomorphism between $[0, 1]$ and an incomplete space, as the continuous image of $[0, 1]$ is necessarily compact, and hence complete.